# How to work out if an IEEE 754 floating point number is normalized?

Tags: floating-point, number-formats

How do I tell whether a particular IEEE 754 floating point number is a normalized floating point number?  Is there some way to recognize an IEEE 754 normalized floating point number?

Answer (score 2):

For [single-precision floating-point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) you need to check if the following condition holds for the exponent $e$: $0 < e < 255$. The exponent occupies bits $30 .. 23$ (including both ends) of a floating-point number.

For [double-precision floating-point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) you need to check if $0 < e < 2047$. The exponent occupies bits $62 .. 52$ in this case.

Essentially, for [IEEE 754 floating-point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) one has to check that the bits of the exponent are not all 1's and not all 0's. All zero bits correspond either to [subnormal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) or to [signed zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero). And when all bits of the exponent are ones it corresponds to $+\infty, -\infty$ or [NaN (not a number)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).

Comment: This is entirely true. But, depending on your needs, you may need to also check zeros (there is a positive and a negative zero) which can be considered either as denormalised numbers (exponent=0), or as special cases.

Comment: The question is about *normalized* numbers, but neither positive nor negative zeros are normalized.

Comment: This answer contains no explanation whatsoever. Since we're talking about computer _science_, we should be looking at floating point numbers expressed in any number of bits, not just some particular numbers of bits that are currently popular.

Comment: @DavidRicherby (1) The 1st version of the question contains a link to several 32-bit numbers (expressed in the hexadecimal format), and IEEE 754 is the standard de-facto in this area. (2) [William Kahan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Kahan) [among the others] has put a lot of effort into designing the IEEE 754 standard. To numerical analysts it was a major breakthrough at the time. (3) I don't think it is possible to give a *concrete* answer without a specified format.